# Ionic 3 - How to create a responsive ion-item inside an ion-list virtualScroll?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a virtual scroll using ion-list and ion-item in my Ionic 3 app.

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="myArray">
    <ion-item *virtualItem="let myItem"></ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

ion-item's dimensions need to be a % (percentage) of the device's view port.

I'm specifying the dimensions of elements nested inside ion-item in % via css in order to make them responsive on all devices.

The problem is, I also need to specify approxItemWidth and approxItemHeight in %, but they can only be specified in px.

How do I solve this issue and make a virtualScroll responsive?

I thought about detecting the screen width and height via javascript and translating the % into px myself for approxItemWidth and approxItemHeight, but since this kind of solution seems pretty easy to implement it makes me wonder if there's a reason this is not possible by design?

Ionic is a mobile framework so the team behind it must have taken responsiveness into consideration when creating virtualList.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

**approxItemWidth** can be specified either `px` or `%` units.

> The approximate width of each item template's cell. This dimension is
>   used to help determine how many cells should be created when
>   initialized, and to help calculate the height of the scrollable area.
>   This value can use either px or % units. Note that the actual rendered
>   size of each cell comes from the app's CSS, whereas this approximation
>   is used to help calculate initial dimensions before the item has been
>   rendered. Default is 100%. - [source](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/)

As for **approxItemHeight** you can try this:  `[style.height]="myItemHeight"` where `myItemHeight` is set by your component `this.myItemHeight = ... + "px";`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why can't approxItemHeight be set in % and how does setting style.height take care of approxItemHeight? Aren't these 2 different things?

Comment: More about answer above https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-beta11-virtualscroll-approxitemheight-throwing-error/60034/3 Though, I stopped using VirtualScroll for now.

Comment: It doesn't really answer my questions. I'm curious, what do you use as an alternative to VirtualScroll and why did you stop using it?

Comment: I save all data to SQLite and then use *ngFor to show it. VirtualScroll seems unstable.